# BEM concept in CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bem

I've recently played around BEM syntax, I am confused about BEM elements.

I have header which contain logo and login box. So I made structure like this:

```
<header class="header clearfix">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <a href="/" class="header__logo"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 header__login">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <div class="login__email pull-left">
                <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS">
            </div>
            <div class="login__password pull-left">
                <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="PASSWORD">
            </div>
            <div class="login__submit pull-left">
                <button class="uppercase">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

So as you can see I use `.header__logo` and `.header__login` and inside of `.header__login` I used separate block `.login__email`.

So my question is am I going right with BEM concept or my class should be read like:

```
.header__login--email
.header__login--passowrd
.header__login--submit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your case isn't right BEM using, because you can't use **Element** without **Block**:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 header__login">
    <div class="pull-right">
        <div class="login__email pull-left">
            <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS">
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

You must have `.login` block. I'd do something like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 header__login">
    <div class="login pull-right">
        <div class="login__email pull-left">
            <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS">
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Your assumption about modifiers (`.header__login--email`, etc) isn't right  too, because you can't use **Modifier** without **Block**/**Element** and can't use **Element** inside another the same **Element**:

```
<header class="header clearfix">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <a href="/" class="header__logo"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 header__login">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <div class="header__login header__login_email pull-left">
                <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS">
            </div>
            <div class="header__login header__login_password pull-left">
                <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="PASSWORD">
            </div>
            <div class="header__login header__login_submit pull-left">
                <button class="uppercase">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

So, my advice is just to add `.login` block and it'll be OK for **BEM**:

```
<header class="header clearfix">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <a href="/" class="header__logo"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 header__login">
        <div class="login pull-right">
            <div class="login__email pull-left">
                <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS">
            </div>
            <div class="login__password pull-left">
                <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="PASSWORD">
            </div>
            <div class="login__submit pull-left">
                <button class="uppercase">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Also you could use separate blocks, it's OK too:

```
<header class="header clearfix">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <a href="/" class="header__logo"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 header__login">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <div class="login-email pull-left">
                <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS">
            </div>
            <div class="login-password pull-left">
                <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="PASSWORD">
            </div>
            <div class="login-submit pull-left">
                <button class="uppercase">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

**P.S.** I prefer [original BEM name convention](https://en.bem.info/method/naming-convention/):

`.block__element--modifier`
*vs*
`.block__element_modifier` (or `.block__element_modifier_value`).

Answer (score 1):

For those new to this convention , ***The Block, Element, Modifier methodology*** (*commonly referred to as BEM*) is a popular naming convention for classes in `HTML` and `CSS`.*Its main  goal is to help developers better understand the relationship between the **HTML** and **CSS** in a given project.*

You are on right track....

***For dependencies we use*** `__`

```
/* Element that depends upon the block */ 
.btn__price {}
```

***for Modifiers we use*** `--`

```
/* Modifier that changes the style of the block */
.btn--orange {} 
.btn--big {}
```